# Toggle boolean fields from a Queryset using F objects

Tags: python, sql, django, boolean, django-queryset

I've tried these queries with these results:

```
queryset.update(done=not F('boolean'))
{'time': '0.001', 'sql': u'UPDATE "todo_item" SET "done" = True'}

queryset.update(done=(F('boolean')==False))
{'time': '0.001', 'sql': u'UPDATE "todo_item" SET "done" = False'}
```

What I would like is something like this:

```
queryset.update(done=F('done'))       
{'time': '0.002', 'sql': u'UPDATE "todo_item" SET "done" = "todo_item"."done"'}
```

But with

```
SET "done" = !"todo_item"."done"
```

to toggle the boolean value

Comment: Looks like this is finally going to be possible in 4.2: `~F('done')` See [Django ticket 16211](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/16211#comment:53)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am developing django-orm extension, and have already partially implemented the solution to your problem.

```
>>> from django_orm.expressions import F
>>> from niwi.models import TestModel
>>> TestModel.objects.update(done=~F('done'))

# SQL:
UPDATE "niwi_testmodel" SET "done" = NOT "niwi_testmodel"."done"; args=()
```

https://github.com/niwibe/django-orm

Is a partial solution and not very clean. And so far only for postgresql. In a while I'll see how to improve it.

Update: now improved and works on postgresql, mysql and sqlite.

Answer (score 1):

This is the standard way and works pretty well

[conditional expressions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)

I'll explain it simply with an even simpler example :)

suppose we have **Restaurant** objects (model), which has **is_closed** field (BooleanField)

and we want to toggle **is_closed** for object with **pk=1**, this snippet does that:

```
r1 = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=1).update(
    is_closed=Case(
        When(is_closed=True, then=False),
        default=True
    ))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        #update_status
        update_status = (
          "UPDATE csv SET status = (NOT csv.status) "
          "WHERE id = %s")
        print(random_number)
        cursor.execute(update_status, (random_number))
        print("update_status")
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

For boolean values, you can use the more Pythonic `not F()` and for bit negation on fields, use `~F()`