# Toggle boolean fields from a Queryset using 'not F()'

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-queryset

I added a new action to toggle Users `is_staff` property. But I noticed that using the method below, can only toggle from `True` to `False`. The other way round doesn't seem to work(ie. from `False` to `True`).

**admin.py**

```py
from django.db.models.expressions import F

actions = ['toggle_staff']
def toggle_staff(self, request, queryset):
    queryset.update(is_staff= not F('is_staff'))
```

## EDIT

My solution using iteration is:

```
actions = ['toggle_staff']
def toggle_staff(self, request, queryset):
    for user in queryset:
        user.is_staff = not user.is_staff
        user.save()
```

But I don't think this is optimized for thousands of users. Please, I need help here.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6643314

Comment: Also note Django 4.2 will allow `~F('is_staff')`: see [this commit](https://github.com/django/django/commit/a320aab5129f4019b3c1d28b7a3b509582bc56f9)

Answer (score 1):

You can always iterate over the queryset, it may not be the best performance but if you're only dealing with a few Users at a time you shouldn't notice the difference:

```py
from django.db import transaction

def toggle_staff(self, request, queryset):
    
    with transaction.atomic():

        for user in queryset:
            if user.is_staff: user.is_staff = False
            else: user.is_staff = True
            user.save()
```

## EDIT:

Using [transactions.atomic](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/transactions/) you can significantly improve performance.

Comment: Thank you @Daniel, I actually know about this method. I wanted something that is optimized for thousands of updates for example.

Comment: You can use `transaction.atomic` - it will significantly speed up processing time. See my update.